# Get data from function with observable or get data in html from observable

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I want to use the AutoComplete component from NgZorro:
https://ng.ant.design/components/auto-complete/en

I already used it with static data, no problem.
But now I want use it to get data from a function (not a datasource)

I tried this:

HTML:

`<nz-autocomplete [nzDataSource]="(get_Auto_Complete(xxxx) | async) ?? []" #auto_Sections></nz-autocomplete>`

TS:

```
   get_Auto_Complete(TXT_Colonne_Correspondance_Table_SQL:string):Observable<string[]>
    {
      return this.ElementService.get_Values(xxxx);
}
```

But I have the empty array, whereas the result of the observale returns a array of strings

I tried also this:

HTML:

```
<nz-autocomplete [nzDataSource]="get_Auto_Complete(xxxxx)" #auto_Sections></nz-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```
get_Auto_Complete(TXT_Colonne_Correspondance_Table_SQL:string):string[]
    {
      return this.ElementService.get_Valeurs_Champ(this.Bibliotheque_Selectionnee!.NUA_ID_Bibliotheque!,TXT_Colonne_Correspondance_Table_SQL).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(res=>{
        return res;
      });
```

If I return a array  `['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];` this works.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Update your .ts file function with below code, it might works for you

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

public async get_Auto_Complete(TXT_Colonne_Correspondance_Table_SQL:string): string[] {
    const res: string[] = await lastValueFrom(this.ElementService.get_Valeurs_Champ(this.Bibliotheque_Selectionnee!.NUA_ID_Bibliotheque!,TXT_Colonne_Correspondance_Table_SQL));
    return res;
}
```

Please try above code

Thanks!

Comment: I answered you. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Thx for your answer,
it seems to work better, but I  have a lot of request server side[image]

I dit this:

`public async get_Auto_Complete(champ:Champ): Promise<string[]> { const res: string[] = await lastValueFrom(this.ChampService.get_Auto_Complete(champ.TXT_Nom__Champ!,"Formation")); return res; }`

`<nz-autocomplete [nzDataSource]="(get_Auto_Complete(champ) | async) ?? []" #auto_Sections></nz-autocomplete>`

In the backend, the function is executed.

But there are too many request, and the brownser crashes
[image]

Comment: please edit your questions rather than posting this as an answer